# Could not load create coonection in addProduct method

Tags: java, jdbc, java-web-start

```
package com.Foodmart;

import javax.jws.*;

import java.sql.*;

@WebService(name = "FoodMart", serviceName = "FoodMartService", portName = "FoodMartHtt)
public class FoodmartWS {

    ProductDetails prod = new ProductDetails();

    @WebMethod(operationName = "check")
    public boolean Authenticate(String user, String pass) {
        PreparedStatement psmt = null;
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            c = ConnectionDB.getConnection();
            String selectSQL = "select * from Employee where Username=? and Password=?";
            psmt = c.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
            psmt.setString(1, user);
            psmt.setString(2, pass);
            psmt.executeQuery();
            c.close();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

In this Method Error in AddProduct

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "AddProduct")
    public ProductDetails ProdcutAdd(int prodid, double qty) {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("try");

//here i am not able to create another one connection
            con = ConnectionDB.getConnection();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Food", "root", "manager1");
            String selectSQL = "select Product_Id,Product_Name,Product_Price,Product_Qty from Products where Product_Id=?;";
            System.out.println("bbefore prepared");
            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, prodid);
            System.out.println("before result set");
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("query Executed");
            rs.next();
            prod.setProductId(rs.getInt("Product_Id"));
            prod.setProductName(rs.getString("Product_Name"));
            prod.setProductPrice(rs.getDouble("Product_Price"));
            prod.setProductQty(rs.getInt("Product_Qty"));
            System.out.println("obj set");
            con.close();
            System.out.println("in" + prod);
            return prod;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you add stack trace of the exception you get. It would help as there could be many reasons for connection not been created

Comment: This is the most unreadable post I ever read. Please format next time. So people who want to help you can read the post easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you add this line after you get your connection :

```
con = ConnectionDB.getConnection();
//con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Food", "root", "manager1");
```

So just delete it or comment it.

**Note**
you missed a `")` here in the end, so this can also make a problem :

```
@WebService(name = "FoodMart", serviceName = "FoodMartService", portName = "FoodMartHtt)
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: @webservice ..for creating service